# How to Toggle (Hide/Show) in Lightning with no Delay or Resizing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I'm conditionally toggling sections in a Lightning Component that each contain a `lightning:datatable`, and I'm stuck in a bind of choosing either the table resizing when the section is first expanded (using `style="display:none"`) or having a slight delay when the section is expanded and collapsed (using `aura:if`). I've tried some other ways using css to conditionally display ([specifically ones that still allow machine reading](https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/)), but I can't get anything to render the table fully in the section before expanding. I'd like to not use `aura:if` with the slight delay since one of the huge improvements of Lightning/Javascript over Visualforce is the immediacy of client-side actions.

Any thoughts on how to maintain the immediacy of css with correct table sizing?

`display:none` code (table resizes on initial expand):

```
<div style="{!v.expanded ? '' : 'display:none;'}">
    <lightning:datatable/>
</div>
```

`aura:if` code (slight delay when expand/collapse):

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.expanded}">
    <lightning:datatable/>
</aura:if>
```